# Writing into XMP and EXIF Metadata from attribute table values in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, imagery, metadata, exif

I've already learnt how to read EXIF and XMP data's from JPG. Now I would like to write from value in attribute table into their XMP and EXIF tags.

This code Import EXIF / XMP , and I would like to do the opposite.

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

layer = iface.activeLayer()
dpr = layer.dataProvider()

layer.startEditing()
apr_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("apr")
exp_ind  = layer.fields().indexFromName("exp")
fyd_ind = layer.fields().indexFromName("fyd")

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    file_path = feature["photo"] 
    print(file_path)
    img = Image.open(file_path)
    exif = { TAGS[k]: v for k, v in img._getexif().items() if k in TAGS }
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        s = str(f.read())
    start = s.find('<x:xmpmeta')
    end   = s.find('</x:xmpmeta')
    xmp   = s[start:end+12].replace("\\n","\n")
    tree  = ET.XML(xmp)
    apr = exif["FNumber"][0]/exif["FNumber"][1]
    exp = exif["ExposureBiasValue"][0]
    fyd = tree[0][0].attrib['{http://www.dji.com/drone-dji/1.0/}GimbalPitchDegree']

    dpr.changeAttributeValues({ feature.id():{apr_ind: apr,
                                            exp_ind: exp }})
layer.commitChanges()
print("COMPLETED")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`pyexiv2` Solution:**

Select layer and run the script. You have to change values to string for non-string fields using `str()` method. This solution is about layers which were created by ImportPhotos plugin. For other layers, you must specify the file path related to feature.

```
from pyexiv2 import Image

layer = iface.activeLayer()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    image = Image(feature["Path"]) # or Image("full_path_of_file_related_to_the_feature")
    metadata = image.read_all()

    metadata["EXIF"]["Exif.Image.Make"] = feature["Camera Mak"]
    metadata["XMP"]["Xmp.drone-dji.FlightYawDegree"] = str(feature["fyd"])
    metadata["XMP"]["Xmp.drone-dji.GimbalYawDegree"] = str(feature["gyd"])

    image.modify_all(metadata) # write new values to image file
```

Comment: I get this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyexiv2', how can I solve it?

Comment: You should install it. https://pypi.org/project/pyexiv2/

Comment: I've installed pyexiv2: C:\Windows\System32>python -m pip install pyexiv2
Requirement already satisfied: pyexiv2 in c:\progra~1\qgis3~1.10\apps\python37\lib\site-packages (1.3.0)

but I still get an error after running the script : OSError: [WinError 127] La procédure spécifiée est introuvable

Comment: Is pyexiv2 working in python 3.7 ? this solution doesn't work for me because I can't use pyexiv2 module. Is there another solution using PIL ?

Comment: what is the Qgis and python that you use to be able to umport pyexiv2 ?

Comment: I use QGIS 3.4 (installed by [OSGeo4W Network Installer](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)), Windows 10 64bit, Python 3.7. I couldn't install for QGISes installed by standalone installer, too.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use pyexiv2 to set exif information in JPG files, but when I import the library in a script QGIS script crash.

I found a solution using the library exif:

https://pypi.org/project/exif/

It's so easy to use, and with Qgis I don,'t have any problem.

In this code I insert GPS coordinates to a snapshot of screen:

```
from exif import Image
with open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
    my_image = Image(image_file)

my_image.make = "Python"
my_image.gps_latitude_ref=exif_lat_ref
my_image.gps_latitude=exif_lat
my_image.gps_longitude_ref= exif_lon_ref
my_image.gps_longitude= exif_lon

with open(file_name, 'wb') as new_image_file:
    new_image_file.write(my_image.get_file())
```